# How to do cross stack references between aws nested stacks in cdk

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have two nested stacks in my cdk app.

```
export default class mainAppStack extends Stack {
 
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    new NestedStackOne(this, "nested-one");
    new nestedStackTwo(this, 'nested-two);
  }
}


export class nestedStackOne extends cdk.NestedStack {
  constructor( scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.NestedStackProps ) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    new new cognito.UserPool(this, `Userpool`, {
     // ...configs
    });
  });

 }


export class nestedStackTwo extends cdk.NestedStack {
  constructor( scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.NestedStackProps 
  ) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    
  });

 }
```

I want to pass the arn of the user pool defined in nested stack one to stack two. I have been struggling to find a way to do this days. AWS doc is no help. How do I do this? How to refer between nested stacks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **CfnOutput** to export the values cross-stack, and use **core.Fn.import_value("export_name")** to use it in the other stack. This should allow you to import the ARN within the account, so the nested structure shouldnt matter.

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.CfnOutput.html